# Tiaga to JIRA migration options

Tags: json, csv, migration, jira, taiga

## Purpose

My company is looking at migrating **to** JIRA from our current story tracker [Taiga](https://tree.taiga.io).

## Minimal Goal

At a minimum we are looking to migrate the following items:

- Issues
- User Stories
- Epics
- Sub Tasks

We are not interested in migrating the project name, settings user's etc, all of this is easy to set up in JIRA.

## Looking For

We have looked for hours trying to find a migration tool or plugin to no avail. We ideally are looking for something, even a script that would make moving all of the above easy as there is a large data set.

Looking over the [JIRA documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/importing-data-from-csv-776636762.html) around importing, they do not have native support for Taiga and the data that is export is difficult to get into the format (CSV or JSON) that they require.

Hoping to find a hidden gem that this community is aware of for the migration.

Answer (score 2):

Both Tiaga and JIRA have a REST API that allows you to script this. If you're familiar with REST APIs this should be reasonably simple.

Taiga's REST API documentation is available [here](https://taigaio.github.io/taiga-doc/dist/api.html).

For JIRA you could use one of these REST resources:

- [Create issue: POST /rest/api/2/issue](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/issue-createIssue)
- [Create issues in bulk: POST /rest/api/2/issue/bulk](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/issue-createIssues)